# jQuery Selector returns null while DOM functions work just fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I need to use the jQuery selector, but it is returning null. Plain, old DOM functions work. I am trying to manipulate this:

```
<ul id="lhs_container">LI elements and HTML</ul>
```

Here is my test code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if(document.getElementById("lhs_container")){
      console.log("DOM was there");             //this is logged in the console
      console.log($("#lhs_container").html());  //this blows up (error below)
   }
});
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of null
at HTMLDocument
```

I have tried other jQuery manipulators as well (append, etc) and they all cause an error. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this? I am pulling my hair out!

Comment: The reason is unknown to me (not enough information), but clearly, `$` is not `jQuery` inside your document ready. Something is overriding it **after** that script declaration.

Comment: jQuery() will never return null.  https://jsfiddle.net/gcqy95ag/   It will always return an empty jQuery object if the element is not found.  So as ^^^ suggested, this would seem to say `$` is not jQuery in your case.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon you were right! This is an "application in a box" that allows customization via jQuery/JavaScript. They have their own jQuery library, but it was not loading in time for my script so I called my own library. Their implementation did not support $, so the $(document).ready() was working but by the time it got to the $ selector the other library had loaded and overridden.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   if(document.getElementById("lhs_container")){
      console.log("DOM was there");
      console.log($("#lhs_container").html());
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="lhs_container">LI elements and HTML</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the output correct. Check whether you added the jquery library correctly.